# ID this Book: Faculty at Second-Rate Magic University Saves the World

Tags: story-identification

I read this book a few years ago, but I don't think it was new then.  Now I can't find it.  The protagonist is a faculty member at a second-rate magic university, on a world dominated by a race of godlike magicians thought to be aliens.  The protagonist and his ragged band of not-all-that-talented friends find themselves reluctantly drawn into what turns out to be a battle between good and evil for the future of the planet.  Along the way they make a surprising discovery about the nature of the superior beings.  What is the title of this book?  Who wrote it?

Comment: I doubt that it's James Alan Gardner's [*Trapped*](http://www.amazon.com/Trapped-League-Peoples-Bk-6/dp/0380813300) , although taken point-by-point it matches oddly well (2nd rate school, godlike magicians, aliens).

Comment: Woking from memory alone, it sounds a bit like Stepen Goldin's Assault On  The Gods.